# ERROR TypeError: platformFormService.getTaskCandidateGroupId is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-error

Есть класс с такой функцией.

```
@Injectable()
export class PlatformFormService {
 public getTaskCandidateGroupId(): string {
      const task: any = this.platformStateService.getSelectedTask();
      if (task && task._embedded && task._embedded.identityLink && task._embedded.identityLink.length > 0) {
        return task._embedded.identityLink[0].groupId;
      }
      return undefined;
  }
}
```

в разных классах функция работает корректно.
Но вот тут ее вызовы валиться с ошибкой.

```
export function validateDocuments(platformService: PlatformFormService): ValidationErrors | null {

  const platformFormService: any =  PlatformFormService;
  const candidateGroupId: string = platformFormService.getTaskCandidateGroupId();
}
```

как мне функцию getTaskCandidateGroupId() ее вызвать?

если вызываю через переменную в методе вот так

```
const candidateGroupId: string = platformService.getTaskCandidateGroupId();
```

то падает ошибка `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTaskCandidateGroupId' of undefined`

Comment: Попробуйте `const platformFormService: any = new PlatformFormService();` И это у вас не js, а скорее всего ts. Angular?

Comment: да это ts, и как вы сказали сработало

Answer (score 0):

В данном методе лишняя строчка

```
const platformFormService: any =  PlatformFormService;
```

В ней в локальную переменную сохраняется сам класс. Так как метод не статичный, при попытке вызвать его непосредственно у класса - приводит к ошибке.

Вместо этого нужно воспользоваться переданным параметром. Для этого достаточно удалить указанную строку.